# How do I increase a float value in a text file using bash on Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

$ cat orders

```
2016 apples .20

2016 oranges .10

2013 bananas .17

2016 berries .30
```

I want to increase the cost of each fruit by 0.02

```
2016 apples .22

2016 oranges .12

2013 bananas .19

2016 berries .32
```

What is the easiest way to accomplish this using bash in Linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a quick one-liner using awk

```
awk 'NF>=3{$3+=0.02}1' orders
```

Comment: can you modify the answer with data as <file> in angular to suggest it is the variable content. As in this case it would be  awk 'NF>=3{$3+=0.02}1' orders . For each line it an program it can be used in conjunction with echo and | .

Answer (score 0):

If the prices are always below .98 and always with two digits:

```
echo "2016 apples .20
2016 oranges .10
2013 bananas .17
2016 berries .30" | while read year fruit preis
do 
  price=${preis/./}
  echo year fruit .$((price+2))
done
```